# i want my Side nav open in desktop or laptop but close in mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with side nav is there a way i can instantly open side nav in desktop while in mobile phone its closed ?? Here is my code . It try class="active" but it keeps side nav close.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dash</title>
</head>

<body class="active">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="top_navbar">
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="profile">
                <div class="brandcolor">

                <img src="image/logo.png" alt="profile_picture">
                <h3><b>Dashboard</b></h3>
                <p><b>admin</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></span>
                        <span class="item">My Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  <script>
       var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
    hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("active");
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely would not want to use javascript for this. The best-practice way is to display based not on device type, but rather width of the viewport, using CSS media queries.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  div {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

or

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    display: none;
  }
}
```